# variable with class name

Tags: c#, linked-list, nodes

Can anybody explain me this line of code?

```
public class Node {

// in the below line what is next and why the class name("node") is used 
//with it
public Node next;
//what is object here and what is data
public Object data;
}
```

Comment: It's an object or element or "node" in a linked list. Look up "linked lists". The data is whatever you need it to be (whatever you need a list of). Where did you see this code?

Answer (score 1):

`Object` is the .net `System.Object` type

And `public Node nexy` is simply declaring a variable with the same type as of the class you're in, which is `Node` class.

Comment: public node{} // in this declaration of class no data type is mentioned what are you talking about??

Comment: @AsadUllah the data type for this variable is `Node`, the same class it's located in. it's so simple man, basic programming.

Comment: i didn't get it, sorry